# GCM Architeture Android

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-messaging

I have some doubts of how it's the best practices about GCM and Android architeture.

Wich one of this approaches is "correct" or recomended.

a) When I receive notification from GCM, I show a notification, get the payload and insert directly into the database.

b) When I get a notification from GCM, I show a notification and wait the user to interact with it. When the user clicks in the notification, I open some activity and make the call to the rest method (my server), loading my data.

Thank's.

Comment: I usually go with the first one, because when you receive a notification, chances are you are connected to a network, while when the user clicks the notification, you may not be. (example of a wifi tablet.). I think having a notification about new data, but not being able to see those data is totally frustrating, so I only display the notification when the data is fully saved.

Comment: on the other hand, if you send a lot of notifications, it can be considered best not to connect to the your server each time, but rather wait for the user to acknowledge it, in order to make only 1 server call instead of 10.